# BigQuery external table cache result cache, is it invalidated automatically if we add new files?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

BigQuery just announced cache result set support when using external tables from Google cloud storage, which is fantastic, not clear though from the documentation, how BigQuery knows if new files arrived or changed in a cloud storage bucket, and hence invalidated the cache ?

or it is up to the user to invalidate it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the documentation has not been updated yet.  Per my test, you do not need to invalidate the cache manually, as soon as I updated the underlying storage file, the query re-ran fully.